# Using XMLHttpRequest with Google Calendar API v3 Calendars:get Request

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I can't seem to get the XMLHttpRequst method to work properly with the Calendars:get request from the Google Calendar API.
 For example, a calendarId with "myemail@gmail.com" works properly, but When it includes a "#" character like `"en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"` it will return a 401 error and `"#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com"` returns a 404 error.
  I'm assuming the request is registering the hash sign as a fragment and the rest as a fragment identifiers?  Is there any way around this while still using XMLHttpRequest?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarId +
  '?access_token=' + accessToken);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.setRequestHeader('responseType', "json");
xhr.setRequestHeader('timeMin', (new Date(today.getFullYear(), 
  today.getMonth(), today.getDate())).toISOString());
xhr.setRequestHeader('showDeleted', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('singleEvents', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('maxResults', 30);
xhr.setRequestHeader('orderBy', "startTime");
xhr.send(null);
```

In the Network tab of the chrome inspect tool, only the part of the request url before the "#" appears to be sent in comparison to the other calendarId's without #'s.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming the request is registering the hash sign as a fragment and the rest as a fragment identifiers?

Yes

> Is there any way around this while still using XMLHttpRequest?

The same way as for any other URL used by any other tool.

Don't shove data into URLs (or any other data format) without properly escaping it.

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + 
    encodeURIComponent(calendarId) +
   '?access_token=' + 
    encodeURIComponent(accessToken)
```